Could inflatable habitats be used on an artificial gravity station?
If you take an inflatable module such as the Sierra Space's LIFE, could you arrange them all around the ring of an artificial gravity station? My main question here is regarding the structural integrity of the modules. We know from BEAM and Sierra's testing that these modules are surprisingly durable, more durable in some regards than traditional space station modules - however, could they withstand the rotational force of a station?
My gut instinct tells me either the answer is obviously yes, because they can withstand 1G on Earth, or "it's complicated."

If you're asking whether any inflatable habit could be engineered to withstand centrifugal gravity, the answer is yes. If you're asking if existing inflatable modules, not engineered specially for this purpose, could withstand a centrifugal gravity configuration, you'd have to specify more (desired acceleration, how the modules are configured) and we'd need to know the loads the interface to the module can handle, which might not be public information. I haven't checked.

I'm kind of baffled trying to imagine how you would actually use such an environment. Are you suggesting the people inside are walking and constructing living spaces on the interior surface of the inflatable bag? Are you imagining a torus station where the enclosed part of the torus is replaced with a bunch of inflatable bags?

@DarthPseudonym Sierra Space's modules have rigid interiors - like multilevel floors - installed on the interior of the modules. It is not simply "a bag."

@WasatchWind So again, how are you imagining having this thing attached to your rotating station? Are you thinking of having the inflatables on the outside, hanging like fruit, or are you imagining sitting them on the inside of the ring, laying on the interior surface? Whether the bag has foldable floors inside it doesn't really change things, the question is how this is arranged relative to gravity. If that question doesn't seem relevant to you, then I think I need a clearer idea of what you're asking about.

I think there is a reasonable question in here somewhere. It might be "Could an inflatable module designed for microgravity be used on a spacecraft rotating to generate artificial gravity, or would it have to be redesigned/reinforced?"or perhaps our usual "What would be the challenges of using X for Y?" where you fill in X and Y with your target item and scenario.

@DarthPseudonym I'm sorry. I'm not an engineer and so I don't think of every single option in this scenario. I just wanted some kind of answer of if inflatable modules could be used in a rotating space station.

Okay, I understand.  The reason I think it's important is because dealing with tension loads vs compression loads is a very different engineering challenge.  I think the answer is ultimately the same in both cases -- you'd need a structure specifically designed to handle the forces -- but the 'why' depends on what kind of loads you're talking about.

First, to address something you said, I'm not sure the LIFE modules can actually withstand 1g on earth. All the photos I've seen indicate that all they've constructed so far are loose kevlar "bags" with no internal structure at all. The ground testing to this point always involves dropping the "bag" over a steel truss that supports its weight while they perform inflation tests.
You have probably seen the burst test photos like this one:

That's not standing up under its own strength, though. Here, one of the test rigs has the two pieces separated, so you can see the test stand's support struts, which are not part of the LIFE structure, and designed specifically to operate under earth gravity:

I'm sure the final product will have some sort of internal structural spars, possibly even fairly strong ones to handle the loads involved in launching the pod, but it's unlikely that whatever foldable internal dividers it's equipped with will be designed for use under acceleration.
So I guess as far as an answer goes, there are three parts:

We can't say what the final structural limits will be for LIFE or any other project will be until it's actually done and in production. LIFE is still early in its development cycle, trying to prove that the bag can be a viable pressure vessel. While they've published some pictures of what they want to do, those are what I would consider "aspirational" rather than technical documents, and should not be used to determine what the limits of the intended final design will be. Designs can and will change between the original plan and the final product.

While inflatable habitats as a concept should be usable under rotational gravity, it would almost certainly require a habitat designed with artificial gravity in mind. Everything from equipment to flooring would need to be firmly affixed to some kind of solid interior support capable of handling the load.

The specific design of such a habitat would depend on how the inflatable unit is meant to connect to the rotating base and how much gravity the system is meant to generate. Compression forces and tension forces are very different in terms of material strength and potential failure modes, which would result in very different design concerns, and naturally a system designed to operate under 1g would be quite different from a system designed to be under 0.2g.


